# view file is not load in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3, hmvc, hmvc-codeigniter

`store_items` controller

```
<?php 
class store_items extends MX_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function create(){
        $this->load->library('session');

        $this->load->module('site_security');
        $this->site_security->_make_sure_is_admin();
        $data['view_module'] = "store_items";
        $data['view_file'] = "create";
        $this->load->module('templates');
        $this->templates->admin($data);
    }
```

This is create.php

```
<h1>Add new items</h1>


i m not able to load create.php file in the browser 
create file is not loaded
what is the issue in loading the view file
The view file ie create is not loading in the browser
```

i m not able to load create.php file in the browser 
    create file is not loaded
    what is the issue in loading the view file
    The view file ie create is not loading in the browser

Answer (score 0):

try to load module like this

```
$this->load->module('templates/admin',$data);
```